# Cypress Kendo dropdown List

Tags: angularjs, automation, kendo-grid, cypress, kendo-ui-angular2

I am working on automating a BI tool and I ran into a kendo dropdown list, I have not been able to figure out how to click and open the dropdown and then pick the element that I want to navigate too.

Please see the attached screenshot and I will really appreciate you'll help because this is an important project.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try the following:

```
// open dropdown
cy.get("Select dropdown arrow").click();
```

and then when drop-down is open

```
// click on any option of your choice
cy.get("option_locator").click();
```

Comment: 'Thanks a lot. I used the syntax and it worked.                                                                       
    I used the following                                                                                                                   
  cy.get("kendo-dropdownlist").click();
    cy.wait(5000);
    cy.contains("Option_Locator").click()